# Cypress - Error message doesn't match code

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

[image: Error shows contains() instead of expect]

As you can see - the error message is about the `cy.contains()` command, pointing on the `expect()` code line.
Cypress doesn't let me know what the true error is - why the test fails.
My test is based on a page class which is added below.
The relevant class functions -

```
class NewAppointment {
    
    selectSeverity(value) {
        cy.get("#severities").select(value)
    }

    chooseAppointmentDate(value) {
        cy.get("[data-handler='selectDay']").contains().click()

    }
}
export default NewAppointment
```

And the code section which fails -

```
       cy.get("#severities").should(($severitiesArray) => {
           expect($severitiesArray.get(0)).to.have.property('childElementCount', 6) 
       })
       .then(($severitiesArray) => { let optionVal = new Array()
       optionVal = $severitiesArray.children()
       let optionalValue = optionVal[Math.floor(Math.random() * optionVal.length) + 1]
       addAppointment.selectSeverity(optionalValue.text)
       })
```

Does anyone know why this happens and/or how to solve it?

edited -
As asked - the DOM structure:
[image]

and also the doctors section -

```
cy.get("#doctors").should(($doctorSelect) => {
            expect($doctorSelect.get(0)).to.have.property('childElementCount', 7)
       })
       .then(($doctorSelect) => {
        let optionArray = new Array()
        optionArray = $doctorSelect.children()
        let optionalValue = optionArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * optionArray.length) + 1]
        addAppointment.selectDoctor(optionalValue.text)
       })
        addAppointment.chooseAppointmentDate(dateValue)
        cy.get(("#schedule"), { timeout: 30000 }).should(($appointments) => { 
           expect($appointments.children()).to.have.length.of.at.least(1)
        })
```

Comment: There is some issue with `$severitiesArray `. Can you do a `cy.log($severitiesArray)` inside should and let me know what you get as output?

Comment: The output is, as expected - <select#severities.form-control>

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the dom structure of the select dropdown?

Comment: How does class `addAppointment` look? You show class `newAppointment` but call `addAppointment.selectSeverity`, so is there any difference between the two classes?

Comment: Also, your error message is about doctors, yet the code shown is about severities. If there are logical problems to be ironed out, please show the code that causes the errors.

Comment: added the information needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[cy.contains](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains.html#Syntax) Requires argument as string. Seems like you need to pass the argument to the ,contains() in the function chooseAppointmentDate(value)

```
class NewAppointment {
    
    selectSeverity(value) {
        cy.get("#severities").select(value)
    }

    chooseAppointmentDate(value) {
        cy.get("[data-handler='selectDay']").contains(value).click()

    }
}
export default NewAppointment
```